# Unable to pull from remote server

Tags: git

I executed a git pull command. But had this issue.

```
$ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.my_repository.com.vn/fsoft/meta-packages.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

It seemed that http protocol had problem. I already check the connection - it's ok.

Who knows where this issue come from ?

Comment: Remove / at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have static routing on my network

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.5.0/24 gw 10.88.124.165 dev eth0
```

Enter below command on both my PC 192.168.5.1 and Gateway PC 10.88.124.165 above.

```
git config --global http.proxy ""
git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
```

Everything is okay now.

Comment: Nice! Interesting, thanks for the contribution, I will take in consideration this answer for the future.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely due to you not having the correct permissions or being authorized correctly on the remote server.

> **403 FORBIDDEN**
>
> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access. The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials. The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials. However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.
>
> Source: [HTTP Status Codes](https://httpstatuses.com/403)

Are you sure you are authorized and have the correct permissions to access the remote repo?

Comment: It seemed not to be relative to permissions and authorization. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Could be for the git version, 1.7.10 has some issues with https connections. Then check if you have the rometes configured:

```
git remote -v
# View existing remotes
origin  https://github.com/github/reactivecocoa.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/github/reactivecocoa.git (push)
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa.git
# Change the 'origin' remote's URL
git remote -v
# Verify new remote URL
origin  https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa.git (push)
```

Then you can do `git pull`

source https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/

Comment: I am using git version 2.7.4

Comment: @ThảoHoàngMinh great, and have you set all the remotes correctly?